# Julia language: is there a t-test?

Tags: julia

I am quite new to Julia language. I would like to know if this language implements some statistical tests, in particular t-test for comparison of means.And if so, how can I invoke it?

Comment: Google `julia t-test` - first result is the content of the answer below, hence "*This question does not show any research effort*"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [HypothesisTests.jl](https://github.com/JuliaStats/HypothesisTests.jl) for this -- [relevant docs](https://juliastats.org/HypothesisTests.jl/stable/parametric/#t-test).

(See also: The website [juliastats.github.io](http://juliastats.github.io/) neatly lists packages in Julia for stats and ML)

Here's how you could probably go about it:

```
julia> Pkg.add("HypothesisTests")
julia> using HypothesisTests
julia> xs = [1, 2, 3, 4]
julia> ys = [5, 6, 7, 8]
julia> OneSampleTTest(vec(xs), vec(ys))
One sample t-test
-----------------
Population details:
    parameter of interest:    Mean
    value under h_0:          0
    point estimate:           -4.0
    95% confidence interval:  (-4.0,-4.0)

Test summary:
    outcome with 95% confidence: reject h_0
    two-sided p-value:           0.0 (extremely significant)

Details:
    number of observations:   4
    t-statistic:              -Inf
    degrees of freedom:       3
    empirical standard error: 0.0
```

(... above example just illustrates the usage of the function, data does not mean anything).

Comment: Note that this way of using `OneSampleTTest` is only valid when the observations come as pairs, e.g. the same students sampled before and after some treatment. For two samples where the observations didn't come as pairs, it would be better to use `EqualVarianceTTest` after testing that the variance is the same.